# A statement about a curve integral.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function. Also $f$ is holomorphic on disk $D(2i,1)$ and we consider $c$ be close polygonal chain which unite the points $2i, 0, 1, 2i$ (with this order). Then the statment $$\int_{c}f(z)dz=0,$$ is wrong. I can not find a counter example. I also try to prove that with contradiction, by supposing that this statement holds and somehow via Goursat's lemma or Morera's theoreme to continue but it is not working, because my curve not lies in $D(2i,1)$ . Any thought would be helpfull. Thanks.

Comment: Find a meromorphic function with a pole inside the triangle, but none inside the circle.

Comment: @saulspatz for example $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-a},$ where $a$ is the point you said previously, and then 
$\int_c f(z)dz=2\pi i $  because $ind_c(a)=1$. Correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thank you very much @saulspatz

Comment: Warning: there is a technical detail that must be fixed. A meromorphic function is not continuous on all of $\Bbb C$. However, the problem is easily fixed with only a limited adjustment.

Comment: Right this is a problem. You mean I sould extend $f$ over $\{a\}$ continuously?

Comment: @PaulSinclair can you help me about this?

Comment: You cannot extend $f$ continuously to $a$, but you can change $f$ *near* $a$ to be continuous.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I should choose a open ball that $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-a}$ and on complement of the ball take another value?

Comment: You should choose a ball (or other neighborhood) about $a$ that is entirely inside the triangle and outside the disk where $f$ is required to be holomorphic. Change $f$ inside the ball to be continuous (which is *all* it needs to be in there), but outside the ball remains unchanged.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I tried to take the function $f(z)=\overline{z-a},\ z\in \bar{D}(a,r)$ and $f(z)={z-a},\ z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \bar{D}(a,r)$ whitch is continuous on $\mathbb{C}$ , also holomorphic on $\ z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \bar{D}(a,r)$ and cosequently on $D(2i,1)$ but the integral of this $f$ on the triangle is zero. Am I correct? What goes wrong?

Comment: I was discussing fixing the one small issue with the answer saulspatz led you to, not abandoning it to try something else that doesn't work. Also, that $f$ is not continuous  on the boundary of $D(a,r)$ except at two points. Take $f(z) = \frac 1{z-a}$ and modify it to be continuous inside a small enough neighborhood of $a$. Since the triangle is where $f$ has not been modified, integration along it still gives the same answer. The modification of $f$ does not need to be well behaved other than being continuous. You don't need some formula for it.